# EWS body plain text

Tags: text, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I use EWS to get exchange emails, but how can i get plain text from email body, without html?
Now i use this:

```
EmailMessage item = (EmailMessage)outbox.Items[i];
item.Load();
item.Body.Text
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the PropertySet of your item you need to set the RequestedBodyType to BodyType.Text. Here's an example:

```
PropertySet itempropertyset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
itempropertyset.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
ItemView itemview = new ItemView(1000);
itemview.PropertySet = itempropertyset;

FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "subject:TODO", itemview);
Item item = findResults.FirstOrDefault();
item.Load(itempropertyset);
Console.WriteLine(item.Body);
```

Comment: Note that the PropertySet has to be used for both service.FindItems() and item.Load() for this to work properly.

Comment: I am getting this exception on doing this Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObjectPropertyException: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value

Comment: @JNM just FYI. There is a more convenient way to work with Exchange servers than EWS, through Aurinko.io REST API. Example from the docs https://apirefs.aurinko.io/#operation/message

Answer (score 7):

In powershell:

```
    .........    
$message = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage]::Bind($event.MessageData,$itmId)

$PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$PropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text
$message.Load($PropertySet)
$bodyText= $message.Body.toString()
```

Comment: What is `$event` in this case?? `$itmId`???? - I have an EmailMessage, and I'm using the exact same code as your last 4 lines, but it's still returning HTML instead of plaintext. I'll try to remember to come back if I figure it out... :-/

Comment: If anyone else is curious, just use your EWS service object in place of $event.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. All you have to do is set RequestedBodyType property of the property set you are using.

```
    PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.Body);
    propSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
    var email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, propSet);
```

Answer (score 5):

The shortest way to do it is like this:

```
item.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.TextBody, EmailMessageSchema.Body));
```

This has got the advantage that you get both, text-body and html-body.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults, itempropertyset);
```

to load properties for all items

Comment: or if you know item unique id: `PropertySet plainTextPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
                                {
                                    RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text,
                                };

EmailMessage emailMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, uniqueId, plainTextPropertySet);
string body = emailMessage.Body.Text;`