# EWS Read Mail Plain Text Body Getting ServiceObjectPropertyException

Tags: c#, api, exchangewebservices

I have done the following in the code below but still getting a ServiceObjectPropertyException. I am obviously loading the property as advised [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243911/ews-body-plain-text) . Please can anyone help point out what I am doing wrongly

```
this.ExchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

                this.ExchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(mailBox, password);
                this.ExchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://mail.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");                

                PropertySet itemProperty = new PropertySet();
                itemProperty.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;


                SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

                ItemView view = new ItemView(999);
                view.PropertySet = itemProperty;                

                List<ExchangeMailResponse> emails = new List<ExchangeMailResponse>();

                FindItemsResults<Item> emailMessage = this.ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);                               


                foreach (Item mail in emailMessage)
                {

                    ExchangeMailResponse email = new ExchangeMailResponse();


                    mail.Load(itemProperty);                  

                   email.Message = mail.Body.Text;                   


                }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the propertyset your trying to use because you haven't used the BasepropertySet overload and you haven't added any properties your only telling exchange to return the IdOnly. So at a basic level you need to at least add the Body property eg

```
itemProperty.Add(ItemSchema.Body);
```

However you won't be able to use that propertyset in the FindItems Operations so i would suggest you change your code something like

```
        SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

        PropertySet FindItemPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

        ItemView view = new ItemView(999);
        view.PropertySet = FindItemPropertySet;
        PropertySet GetItemsPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        GetItemsPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;


        FindItemsResults<Item> emailMessages = null;
        do
        {
            emailMessages = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view);
            if (emailMessages.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                service.LoadPropertiesForItems(emailMessages.Items, GetItemsPropertySet);
                foreach (Item Item in emailMessages.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Item.Body.Text);
                }
            }
        } while (emailMessages.MoreAvailable);
```

Cheers
Glen