# EWS body plain text Using F#

Tags: f#, exchangewebservices

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243911/ews-body-plain-text) post, I am reading some messages from Exchange and I want the body in plain (non-html) text.  I am doing it in F#. Here is the code:

```
> let exchangeService = new
> ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
> exchangeService.Credentials <- new
> WebCredentials(userName,password,domain)
> exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(email)
> 
> let getEmailText exchangeService itemId =
>     let propertySet = new PropertySet()
>     propertySet.RequestedBodyType <- BodyType.Text
>     propertySet.BasePropertySet <- BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties
>     let message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, itemId, propertySet)
>     message.TextBody
```

The compiler is complaining on this line:

```
propertySet.RequestedBodyType <- BodyType.Text
```

> This expression was expected to have type    Nullable    but here has type    BodyType

How to I make the BodyType.Text Nullable?  Nullable does not work

Comment: Try `propertySet.RequestedBodyType <- Nullable BodyType.Text`

Comment: That is it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
propertySet.RequestedBodyType <- BodyType.Text
```

To this (Just add `Nullable` type):

```
propertySet.RequestedBodyType <- Nullable BodyType.Text
```